# How to output elements in a JSON array with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, output

JSON array defined in scope:

```
$scope.faq = [
        {"Question 1": "Answer1"},
        {"Question 2": "Answer2"}
    ];
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="f in faq">
    {{f}}
</div>
```

Output:

```
{"Question 1": "Answer1"}
{"Question 2": "Answer2"}
```

What I want output to look like:

```
Question 1 - Answer1
Question 2 - Answer2
```

How it seems like it should work:

```
<div ng-repeat="f in faq">
    {{f.key}}-{{f.value}}
</div>
```

... but it doesn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your json array in scope like;

```
$scope.faq = [
        {key: "Question 1",
         value: "Answer1"},

        {key: "Question 2",
         value: "Answer2"}
    ];
```

And in your view;

```
<div ng-repeat="f in faq">
    {{f.key}}-{{f.value}}
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, this works.  I like the alternative:  <div ng-repeat="(question, answer) in faq">
    {{question}} - {{answer}}
</div>, which doesn't require adding key/value, but I think this is more extensible and closer to answering the question.

Answer (score 8):

Due to it being within an array, you will have to loop through the key values of each object.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/TheSharpieOne/QuCCk/

```
<div ng-repeat="value in faq">
    <div ng-repeat="(question,answer) in value">
        {{question}} - {{answer}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Alternately:
If you have just a simple object:

```
$scope.faq = {
     "Question 1": "Answer1",
     "Question 2": "Answer2"
};
```

You could avoid the second repeat

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(question,answer) in faq">
        {{question}} - {{answer}}
</div>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/TheSharpieOne/D3sED/

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.faq = [
    "Answer1",
    "Answer2"
];


<div ng-repeat="answer in faq">
    Question {{$index+1}}-{{answer}}
</div>
```

Comment: This falls down when question is a dynamic value, which it is in the non-trivial, example case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ECMA5 compliant browsers, you could try,

```
<div ng-repeat="f in faq">
    {{Object.keys(f)[0]}}-{{f[Object.keys(f)[0]]}}
</div>
```

Of course, this will only work reliably if your object only has 1 key. If it has more than one key, your best bet will be to write a filter function that gets the key names, which you can then use to extract the relevant keys.

Comment: While working I find it far from being concise and readable. As you have also noticed yourself - adding unrelated keys to your object would break this ngRepeat, which means it's not a good design.

Answer (score 0):

Check my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/NGEcK7iieFRtvt7WP48A?p=preview

ng-repeat needs an array, for each object in the array, you need keys bound with values.