# How to access json object in Ionic / Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I need to access the `firstBill` value in this json:

```
[{
    "companyName": "Madrid",
    "producCompanyId": 4,
    "productCompanyName": "Empresa1",
    "state": {
        "id": 5,
        "description": "Completada sin precios"
    },
    "message": "\nHay otra empresa igual en ACTIVO                                              "
}, {
    "companyName": "Barcelona",
    "producCompanyId": 10,
    "productCompanyName": "Empresa2",
    "companyResultId": "889",
    "state": {
        "id": 4,
        "description": "Completada con precios"
    },
    "prices": {
        "priceList": [{
            "priceId": 699614,
            "companyPriceId": "1091931204",
            "firstBill": 281.96,
            "issuable": true
        }, {
            "priceId": 699609,
            "companyPriceId": "1091931204",
            "firstBill": 251.64,
            "issuable": true
        }, {
            "priceId": 699611,
            "companyPriceId": "1091931204",
            "firstBill": 302.6,
            "issuable": true
        }]
    },
    "message": ""
}]
```

Now I have this code but with errors because of undefined `prices` jsonarray in other (the first one of the previous json) objects:

```
<ion-content class="home">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let oferta of ofertas">
      <h2>{{oferta.companyName}}</h2>
      <pre>{{ oferta.prices.priceList[0] ? oferta.prices.priceList[0] | json }}</pre>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: feels like your first json structure is an array, and prices exists only in a 2nd item in array. those items are objects, but first branch is an array: so, ofera[1].prices.priceList ... use jsonblob or any editor, i think you're not seeing the proper json structure and there is your error...

Comment: yeah, sorry, oferta[0], you're right. could you help me to get the first item in the 'priceList' element? it throws an undefined error

Comment: oferta.prices.priceList[0].firstBill

Comment: if it's not necessary to show all oferta.prices.priceList of every ofertas item, how about use [*ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngIf) `<pre *ngIf="oferta.prices.priceList"> here put another *ngFor iterate through oferta.prices.priceList so you access all firstbill</pre>`

Comment: im not sure if he wants to access all the first bill values or just the first one. What I wrote will get you just the first one as you asked for in comment... anyway paste code on json blob or look at this sort of examples you'll figure it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436084/how-to-output-elements-in-a-json-array-with-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Try the modified code below. Probably this could help you. I added ngIf with some nested div structure.

```
 <ion-list>
          <ion-item *ngFor="#oferta of ofertas">
            <h2>{{oferta.companyName}}</h2>
                  <div *ngIf="oferta.prices">
                   <div *ngFor="#plist of oferta.prices.priceList">
                          <pre>{{ plist | json }}</pre>
                  </div>
            </div>
          </ion-item>
       </ion-list>


 this.ofertas = [{
        "companyName": "Madrid",
        "producCompanyId": 4,
        "productCompanyName": "Empresa1",
        "state": {
            "id": 5,
            "description": "Completada sin precios"
          },

          "message": "\nHay otra empresa igual en ACTIVO                                              "
      }, {
          "companyName": "Barcelona",
          "producCompanyId": 10,
          "productCompanyName": "Empresa2",
          "companyResultId": "889",
          "state": {
              "id": 4,
              "description": "Completada con precios"
          },
          "prices": {
              "priceList": [{
                  "priceId": 699614,
                  "companyPriceId": "1091931204",
                  "firstBill": 281.96,
                  "issuable": true
              }, {
                  "priceId": 699609,
                  "companyPriceId": "1091931204",
                  "firstBill": 251.64,
                  "issuable": true
              }, {
                  "priceId": 699611,
                  "companyPriceId": "1091931204",
                  "firstBill": 302.6,
                  "issuable": true
              }]
          },
          "message": ""
      }]
```